# Android - ActionBar - Back Button

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I've implemented a custom logo for my ActionBar for Android.

Here's the image.[image: Custom Logo]

The issue now that I'm facing is how do I allow myself to be able to click on that back arrow,and bring myself to the previous activity?A huge thank you :D!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the following two things in your code:

**FIRST**:
Go to the Activity's code in which you want to put the back arrow and write the following code after setContentView...

```
getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

**SECOND**:
Go to AndroidManifest.xml file and under the activity tag of another activity(**from** which you want to move after clicking on back arrow) put the following code

```
<activity
    android:name="---------------------"//No change here
    android:label="--------------------"//No change here
    android:parentActivityName="<YourPackageName>.PreviousActivityName >//**Put this code here**
```

Where **PreviousActivity** is the one to which you want to move after clicking the back arrow button.

**FOR EXAMPLE:**

Your code has 2 activities namely Act1 and Act2,and suppose you want to navigate from Act2 to Act1 by pressing the ActionBar back arrow button present in Act2...Here your parentActivity is Act1.

Put the following code in **Act2.java**:---

```
getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

Now go to **AndroidManifest.xml** and put the following code under Act2  tag:
Let's say your package name is:**com.example.stack**

```
<activity
    android:name="---------------------"//No change here
    android:label="--------------------"//No change here
    android:parentActivityName="com.example.stack.Act1 >//**Put this code here**
```

Answer (score 0):

Here: http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/ancestral.html

you will find all answers for this question. If you don't understand something, feel free to ask ;)